# Is there a way to reassemble files split without enumerating all of the parts explicitly?

Tags: linux

I used `split -b 32m "file.bz2" "file.bz2.part-"` to split a file and it created more than 50 parts. From googling, the way I found to reassemble the parts is to `cat file.bz2.part-aa file.bz2.part-ab > file.bz2`, while enumerating all the 50+ parts. Is there an easier way to reassemble the parts wherein I no longer need to list all those parts explicitly?

I'm using Fedora 12.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what wildcards and brace expansion are for. See if `echo file.bz2.part-*` returns the filenames in the desired order, and use `cat file.bz2.part-* > file.bz2` if it does. Otherwise, figure out some other more complex expansion that does.

Comment: +1 and a "Useful use of cat" award.  http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/uuoc/

Answer (score 4):

`split` creates its partial file names in ascending lexicographical order. Since wildcard expansions lists the files in lexicographical order, `cat file.bz2part-* > file.bz2` will concatenate the parts in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for i in `ls file.part-* |sort`; do echo $i; cat $i >> newfile; done
```

Comment: the back ticks were stripped off. add a back tick in front of ls and to the right of sort.

Comment: Fixed, the back ticks are added back as they were intended.